# jQuery UI checkbox button select all problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, checkbox, jquery-ui-button

I am using this to check all checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="all" onclick="$('input[name*=\'selected\']').attr('checked', checked);" />
```

as long as I use the normal checkboxes everything works fine. When I convert all to jQuery UI checkboxes: http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox
They get checked -- but not in a visually -- the colors are not changing. I saw that when a jQuery UI checkbox is checked it gets this attribute `aria-pressed="true"`

Can someone help me understand how can I get this done!

Comment: I don't know anything about jquery, but is it possible to check if a checkbox's aria-pressed attribute is true and if it is check the checkbox? Just an idea.

Comment: You also should consider moving the inline events off to a separate .js file instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('input[name*=\'selected\']').attr('checked', true).button("refresh");
```

Very easily you will:

1. Set the **underlying** radio input
2. Reflect the state on the JQuery UI Button façade

Answer (score 2):

There a [`refresh` method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#method-refresh) to update the visual style after you change the `checked` value programmatically, like this:

```
$('input[name*=\'selected\']').attr('checked', checked).button("refresh")
```

Comment: Nick, there's a missing line: **var checked = true;**